# can configure apache2 for run j2ee applications

Tags: java

can configure apache2 for run j2ee(JSP and servlets) applications using the same apache 2 install by LAMP directly for runing php. please mail me at ajuiet007[at]gmail.com if wither i can do it for the same. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apache httpd is not a JEE container (the 2 was dropped a few years ago). To run JSP and servlets use Apache Tomcat or one of the many available JEE servers.